# Zeta function and a strange set.

Tags: number-theory

For a set E of non-negative integers, let $Q(E)$ be the set of all integers $n =
\Pi_p p^{\alpha (p)} $ where
$\alpha (p) \in E$ for all primes p.

Show that, if $E = \{0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7\},$ then

$$\sum_{n\in Q(E)} \frac {1}{n^s} =\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(5s)}{
\zeta (3s) \zeta (10s )}$$

I really don't understand this question; for one $\alpha (p)=?$
.

Comment: $\alpha(p)$ is the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the question... You need to compute the sum over positive integers that are not divisible by high powers of primes.

Comment: Like would $\alpha(2) =3$? when n=24?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\in Q(E)} \frac {1}{n^s} $$
$$= \Pi_{p}(1+\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{n^{2s}}+\frac{1}{n^{5s}}+\frac{1}{n^{6s}}+\frac{1}{n^{7s}})$$
$$= \Pi_{p}\bigg[(1+\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{n^{2s}})\cdot (1+\frac{1}{n^{5s}})\biggr]$$
$$= \Pi_{p}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{1-\frac{1}{n^{3s}}}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}}\biggr)\cdot\bigg(\frac{1-\frac{1}{n^{10s}}}{1-\frac{1}{n^{5s}}}\biggr)\biggr]$$
$$=\bigg[\bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{\zeta(3s)}}{\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}}\biggr)\cdot \bigg(\frac{\frac{1}{\zeta(10s)}}{\frac{1}{\zeta(5s)}}\biggr)\biggr]$$
$$=\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(5s)}{
\zeta (3s) \zeta (10s )}$$